# How to put a swipe effect in toggle switch made with css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, scss-lint

I am testing this toggle switchs, then I want to verify if is possible put a swipe effect only with these html elements.

```
h1 Pure CSS Toggle Switches
 .centered 
  .card
   label(for='switch1')
     input(type='checkbox' id='switch1')
     span.switch
     span.toggle
```

[Code Pen toggle swicth](http://codepen.io/koenigsegg1/pen/QjZNVP?css-preprocessor=scss)

Comment: It isn't default browser behaviour to activate a label by swipe. Maybe look into a swipe js library.